How to partition data in a warp based on a predicate so all keep items are consecutive
I have a warp full of data, some of which I want to keep and some I want to discard.
I want to store the keep items in contiguous memory.
For example, say I only want to keep prime numbers
input      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
keep prime     2 3   5   7        11
output     2 3 5 7 11

What is the best (fastest/simplest) way to do this for a single warp (32 items) worth of data?

Thanks! I added SC to the tags, do you think the title is ineffective?

I use a lanesBefore function which uses integer intrinsics to generate destinations for different scenarios:
__device__ uint32_t lanemask_lt() { //the other lanemask functions work in a similar way.
    uint32_t result;
    asm ("mov.u32 %0, %%lanemask_lt;" : "=r"(result));
    return result;
}

//on CUDA 12.5 you can use
//cuda::ptx::lanemask_lt();

enum where { lt, le, eq, neq, gt, ge, biggest, smallest, nle, nlt, next };
template <where Where = lt>
__device__ int LanesBefore(const int Mask) {
    static_assert((Where >= lt) && (Where <= next));
    switch (Where) {
        case lt:       return __popc(Mask    & lanemask_lt());
        case le:       return __popc(Mask    & lanemask_le());
        case eq:       return bool(Mask    & lanemask_eq());
        case neq:      return bool((~Mask) & lanemask_eq());
        case gt:       return __popc(Mask    & lanemask_gt());
        case ge:       return __popc(Mask    & lanemask_ge());
        case nle:      return __popc((~Mask) & lanemask_le());
        case nlt:      return __popc((~Mask) & lanemask_lt());
        case biggest:  return 31 - __clz(Mask);
        case smallest: return __ffs(Mask) - 1;
        case next:     return __ffs(Mask & lanemask_ge()) -1;
        default: assert(false); return 0;
    }
}

The lanesBefore expects a bit mask containing a 1 for items to keep and 0 for items to discard and will generate a destination from that mask and the lanemask_lt() which laneid - 1 number of ones set. E.g.: lanemask_lt(lane 7) = 0b1111111 (seven 1s).
for our example data:
Lane 7: data = 7, keepmask = 100010101100, lanemask_lt = 00001111111

keepmask:     100010101100
lanemask_lt   000001111111
and           ------------
popcount(     000000101100) destination = 3

pos:           0 1 2 3
desired output 2 3 5 7 <<-- yes `7` needs to be in position 3.

The full code first reads in a the raw data, then uses a predicate and __ballot_sync to generate a mask.
This mask is run through the lanesBefore function which counts the number of keep items before us to generate the destination index.
const auto laneid = threadIdx.x % 32;
const auto data = numbers[laneid];
numbers[laneid] = 0; //optional: clear out non primes
const auto keep = isPrime(data);
const auto keepMask = __ballot_sync(Everyone, keep); 
const auto dest = lanesBefore<lt>(keepMask);
numbers[dest] = data; //put back primes
__syncwarp();
const auto validCount = popc(keepMask); 

Thus the warp data is compacted in a few instructions.

something similar is here (in the "worked example" code).  stream compaction is used to do warp level radix sort in a few instructions per radix bit iteration
